# How do I .push separate classes into an array one after another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

Using javascript and jquery i'm trying to separate sentences and store them one by one into an array.  This is what I've tried

```
var sentenceArray = new Array();

//SPLITS PARAGRAPHS INTO SENTENCES//
$('#text').each(function() {

    var sentences = $(this).html().replace(/([^.!?]*[^.!?\s][.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g,'<span class="sentence">$1</span>$2');
                    sentenceArray.push(sentences);

});
```

This, though, returns all the sentences combined into the [0] index of the array. How do I separate them?

```
<div id="text">

    Crowds blocked main roads in Sao Paulo and Brasilia, and protesters confronted police in Rio de Janeiro state shortly after the U-turn was announced.
    Earlier, there were clashes before Brazil's football team played Mexico in Fortaleza in the Confederations Cup.
    Protesters are angry at corruption and high spending on next year's World Cup.
    Activists say they have not changed their intention to hold the biggest demonstrations yet on Thursday.
    The BBC's Julia Carneiro, in Sao Paulo, says hundreds of thousands are expected on the streets there before another round of matches in the Confederations Cup.

</div>
```

Comment: What does the text look like ?

Comment: Like this: <span class="sentence">Earlier, there were clashes before Brazil's football team played Mexico in Fortaleza in the Confederations Cup.</span>
<span class="sentence">Protesters are angry at corruption and high spending on next year's World Cup.</span>
<span class="sentence">Activists say they have not changed their intention to hold the biggest demonstrations yet on Thursday.</span>

Comment: If all the sentences are seperated with newlines, that is, you've hit enter at the end of the sentence, you can just split on newlines ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KRNcM/

Comment: They will not all end on the same line, even though that's in the example above, sorry.  Some lines may have more than one sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this , look:

```
var sentenceArray = new Array();

//SPLITS PARAGRAPHS INTO SENTENCES//
var sentences = $(this).html().replace(/([^.!?]*[^.!?\s][.!?]['"]?)(\s|$)/g,'<span class="sentence">$1</span>$2<SENTENCE_END>');

sentenceArray = sentences.split("<SENTENCE_END>");
```

It will be possible in case you're able to make changes to your regular expression.

Comment: This seems to work, but for some reason my CSS .sentence no longer applies styles.. ?

Comment: @Squirrel i don't see some reason for this. we don't even updating your text container . may be you have added some problematic code after this? something like `$(this).text(sentences)` ?

Comment: That brought all the html up front.  '$(this).html(sentences);' works and adds all the styles, but than the SENTENCE_END shows up front in the text, after each sentence.

Comment: `'<span class="sentence">$1</span SENTENCE_END>$2'` this seems to work.  Is that bad for any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your array object is defined incorrectly. Try this as an example:

```
   var array = [];
   array.push('one');
   array.push('two');
   alert(array[0]);
   alert(array[1]);
```